# SQL query for a selection from a table with categories and subcategories

Tags: mysql, sql, select, categories

Structure of the Category table:

- id
- title
- parent_id

Structure of the Item table:

- id
- title
- is_active (0 или 1)
- category_id

[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGvXU.jpg)

Tables are associated with the category_id field by a one-to-many relationship. Those. 1 category can have many items.

The two-level hierarchy in the Category table. This defines the main categories and subcategories. Categories are those records in which parent_id = NULL. And subcategories, these are those records in which parent_id = to some id.

One Item can belong to both the main category (where parent_id = null) and the subcategory (child). Item can be active and not active (0 or 1).

You need to make a query and select from the Category table all the main categories (which have parent_id = null) that have active items (is_active = 1) and which have subcategories also with active itemes.
i.e If the child subcategory has items with is_active = 0, then do not display this category.

I could only choose the main categories in which only active items:

```
SELECT categories.title, count(analyses.id) FROM items
            INNER JOIN categories on items.category_id = categories.id
            WHERE categories.parent_id IS NULL
            AND categories.is_active = 1
            GROUP BY analyses.category_id
            ORDER BY analyses_categories.title
```

But with subcategories can not cope anymore, tell me please who has more experience.

Comment: What have you tried?  Look into using `join` and `exists`.

Comment: School assignment?

Comment: Expected results would be helpful as well as trying it yourself first.

Comment: I can not think of a way to do this in 1 query. I just got to choose the main categories, in which there are only active items.

Comment: Your objectives in this are not very clear.  Try to clear up what you are trying to achive in the final statement.  Also show us what you have come up with first, so we can point you in a direction instead of doing it for you.

Comment: I could only choose the main categories in which only active items:
SELECT categories.title, count(analyses.id) FROM items
            INNER JOIN categories on items.category_id = categories.id
            WHERE categories.parent_id IS NULL
            AND categories.is_active = 1
            GROUP BY analyses.category_id
            ORDER BY analyses_categories.title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you are trying to `count` (just the active items associated with the parent?), but I would use `exists` to find out which have children with active items as well:

```
select c.title, count(*)
from categories c
    join item i on i.category_id = c.id 
where c.parent_id is null and i.is_active = 1 and exists (
    select 1
    from categories c2
        join item i on c2.id = i.category_id
    where c2.parent_id = c.id and i.is_active = 1
)
group by c.title
```

Comment: for some reason an empty result (

Comment: I'm trying to output categories with parent_id = null, which have child categories with active elements + categories with active elements

Comment: @tirael8 Here's a sample demo (seems to work for me): https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c3LUJ6GqZUDod2PrT6Kb9v/0

Comment: With subcategories everything is correct. But still need to add a condition, if item 1 or 2 or 3 are active, then blah1 or blah2 or blah 3 is also output

Comment: @tirael8 Sorry, that's not making much sense.  At this point, rewrite your question with sample data and expected results.  If you don't care about subcategories, remove the `exists` statement above...

Comment: Yes, if I remove exists then it is displayed correctly, only without subcategories. Is it possible to leave 1 and 2 in the same query?

Comment: If some items are not categorized with parent_id = null, then subcategories are not selected. http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2018/06/13/0030/1266/2028786/86/2ef4e8d3c3.jpg 
How to fix this problem? please help me